# Programmatically setting an UIViewController's view and life cycle

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, xib

I have several views in my app targeted for iOS 7+ that show a `MKMapView`. I'd like to have a single `UIViewController` to manage those `MKMapView` views, so I tried to create an `UIViewController` subclass conforming `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

This `MapViewController` class has not an associated `nib` file. Then, in the view controller that manages the view where I want to show a `MKMapView`:

```
self.mapController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
map.delegate = self.mapController;
[self.mapController setView:map];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapController.view];
```

This way, I can see that `viewWillAppear:` method in `MapViewController` is called, but `viewDidLoad:` method isn't.

Is this the correct way to do what I want? Why is `viewDidLoad:` not called?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just add `MKMapView` directly to your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You shouldn't set the `view` property of a `UIViewController`. In fact, you should consider the view hierarchy of a `UIViewController` as private.
- you should use Apple's `UIViewController` containment API to ensure proper invocation of `viewWillAppear:` etc.

So here's what you should do:

The `MKMapView` must be created in `-loadView` of `MapViewController`:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
    map.delegate = self;
    self.view = map;
}
```

When you add the child ViewController to the view hierarchy you should do this:

```
self.mapController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:self.mapController];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapController.view];
[self.mapController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

when you remove the child ViewController from the view hierarchy for whatever reason you should do this:

```
[self.mapController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.mapController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.mapController removeFromParentViewController];
```

For more details about container view controllers please refer to
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

**How does a view controller load its view?**

Apple's view property getter implementation looks a lot like this:

```
- (UIView *)view
{
    [self loadViewIfNeeded];

    return _view;
}

- (void)loadViewIfNeeded
{
    if (_view == nil) {
        [self loadView];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

when you access the `view` property of a view controller, it checks if `view` is actually nil. If it is nil, it invokes `-loadView` and then `-viewDidLoad` before returning `view`.

Therefore when you set the view property before accessing it the first time, `-loadView` and `-viewDidLoad` will never be invoked.